# Hero View's Position Calculated Wrongly During Shared Element Transition

Tags: android, animation, android-toolbar, shared-element-transition, coordinator-layout

I have two activities, Toolbars and CoordinatorLayouts in both of them.

Toolbars can be hidden by scrolling, thanks to CoordinatorLayout.

I'm trying to make a shared element transition between them and these are the steps I've taken so far:

- Set an image view as hero view.
- Set toolbar, navigationbar and status bar as hero too, to avoid an overlay issue.

Here is my problem:

When shared element animation starts, hero toolbar slides from up to down leading to whole screen move up to down.

**Because hero imageview's position is calculated before this animation, it flashes to its final position after a move animation.**

Is there a way to let animator calculate the imageview's final position correctly?

I'm not sure that I have addressed my problem sufficiently, so I can provide extra information with comments.

Sorry for long question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue. I am also facing same. Please reply

Comment: Unfortunately no, sorry. I eventually changed the way I animate views.